# How to run Akka Scheduler once in a cluster?

Tags: java, akka, akka-cluster

I want to run a single instance of a Akka scheduler in a cluster. Currently my scheduler is working fine in my local but not as expected. The scheduler picks orders from DB and pushes to Kafka topic.
I am using akka 2.5.6(Java). I have gone through the [official Doc](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/cluster-singleton.html)  but didn't offer that much help. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

```
public class OrderReprocessActor extends UntypedActor {


    LoggingAdapter log = Logging.getLogger(getContext().system(), this);
    OrderProcessorJdbcConnection orderProcessorJdbcConnection;
    private final String SELECT_QUERY_TO_GET_FAILED_ORDER="SELECT * FROM ORDER_HISTORY WHERE ORDER_STATUS = ?";
    CommonPropsUtil commonPropsUtil;

    final Cluster cluster = Cluster.get(getContext().system());           

    public static Props getProps() {
        return Props.create(OrderReprocessActor.class);
    }

    @Inject
    public OrderReprocessActor(OrderProcessorJdbcConnection orderProcessorJdbcConnection , CommonPropsUtil commonPropsUtil){
        this.orderProcessorJdbcConnection = orderProcessorJdbcConnection;
        this.commonPropsUtil = commonPropsUtil;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Throwable {

        String failedStatus = (String) message;
        List<OrderHistory> failedOrderList =  getOrders(failedStatus);
        pushOrderToKafka(failedOrderList);
        String intervalSeconds = commonPropsUtil.getCommonPropsValueForKey(CommonConstants.ORDER_REPROCESSOR_SCHEDULER_INTERVAL);
        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(intervalSeconds))
        {
            int interval = Integer.parseInt(intervalSeconds);
            getContext().system().scheduler().scheduleOnce(Duration.create(interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
                    () -> {
                        getSelf().tell(failedStatus, ActorRef.noSender());
                    }, getContext().system().dispatcher());
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method takes the failedOrderList and pushes to Kafka Topic
     *
     */
    private void pushOrderToKafka(List<OrderHistory> failedOrders) {

        log.info("Entering pushOrderToKafka()");
        String kafkaOrderTopic = commonPropsUtil.getCommonPropsValueForKey(CommonConstants.KAFKA_SUBMIT_ORDER_TOPIC);
        Properties props = getKafkaProperties();
        Producer<String, Order> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
        for (OrderHistory orderHistory : failedOrders) {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            try {
                Order order = objectMapper.readValue(orderHistory.getOrderData().toString(),Order.class);
                log.info("******************Order ID..."+orderHistory.getOrderId());
                producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, Order>(kafkaOrderTopic, orderHistory.getOrderId(), order)).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error("IOException caught , message="+e.getMessage());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                log.error("InterruptedException caught , message="+e.getMessage());
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                log.error("ExecutionException caught , message="+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        producer.close();
        log.info("Exiting pushOrderToKafka()");
    }

    /**
     * This method return kafka connection properties
     * @return
     */
    private Properties getKafkaProperties() {
        String kafkaBootStrapServers = commonPropsUtil.getCommonPropsValueForKey(CommonConstants.KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(CommonConstants.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS, kafkaBootStrapServers);
        props.put(CommonConstants.KEY_SERIALIZER, VZWCommonConstants.STRING_SERIALIZER);
        props.put(CommonConstants.VALUE_SERIALIZER, VZWCommonConstants.ORDER_SERIALIZER);
        return props;
    }

    /**
     *This method get all the failed Order from DB
     * @return List<OrderReprocessActor.OrderHistory>
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    private List<OrderReprocessActor.OrderHistory> getOrders(String failStatus) throws SQLException {
        log.info("Entering getAllFailedOrdersFromDB()");
        Connection connection = orderProcessorJdbcConnection.getConnection();

        try {
            PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(SELECT_QUERY_TO_GET_FAILED_ORDER);
            pstmt.setString(1,failStatus);
            ResultSet rersultSet = pstmt.executeQuery();
            return getOrdersFromResultSet(rersultSet);
        }catch (SQLException e){
            log.error("SQLException caught while fetching failed Order from DB");
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }finally {
                orderProcessorJdbcConnection.releaseConnection(connection);
        }
        log.info("Exiting getAllFailedOrdersFromDB()");
        return  null;
    }

    /**
     * Retrives order from sql result set
     * @param rersultSet
     * @return
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    private List<OrderHistory> getOrdersFromResultSet(ResultSet rersultSet) throws SQLException {
        List<OrderReprocessActor.OrderHistory> failedOrderList = new ArrayList<>();
        while(rersultSet.next()){
            String orderId = rersultSet.getString("order_id");
            String orderData = rersultSet.getString("order_data");
            OrderHistory orderHistory = new OrderHistory();
            orderHistory.setOrderId(orderId);
            orderHistory.setOrderData(orderData);
            failedOrderList.add(orderHistory);
        }
        return failedOrderList;
    }

    public static class OrderHistory{

        private String orderId;
        private String orderData;
        public String getOrderId() {
            return orderId;
        }
        public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
            this.orderId = orderId;
        }
        public String getOrderData() {
            return orderData;
        }
        public void setOrderData(String orderData) {
            this.orderData = orderData;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your `OrderReprocessActor` a [cluster singleton](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/cluster-singleton.html). From the docs:

> The cluster singleton pattern is implemented by akka.cluster.singleton.ClusterSingletonManager. It manages one singleton actor instance among all cluster nodes or a group of nodes tagged with a specific role. ClusterSingletonManager is an actor that is supposed to be started on all nodes, or all nodes with specified role, in the cluster. The actual singleton actor is started by the ClusterSingletonManager on the oldest node by creating a child actor from supplied Props. ClusterSingletonManager makes sure that at most one singleton instance is running at any point in time.

Comment: hi, I have gone through the link as mentioned in question. But I am unable to understand how to integrate with what I have. In theory I understood what is the way, but code wise I am not clear.

Answer (score 0):

A cluster singleton is created like so:

```
final ClusterSingletonManagerSettings settings =
  ClusterSingletonManagerSettings.create(system);

system.actorOf(
  ClusterSingletonManager.props(
    Props.create(Consumer.class, () -> new Consumer(queue, testActor)),
    TestSingletonMessages.end(),
    settings),
  "consumer");
```

Akka will ensure that the actor is created only on the cluster's leader node.

To use the singleton actor, you ask for a proxy to it via its path:

```
ClusterSingletonProxySettings proxySettings =
    ClusterSingletonProxySettings.create(system);

ActorRef proxy =
  system.actorOf(ClusterSingletonProxy.props("/user/consumer", proxySettings),
    "consumerProxy");
```

These examples are adapted from [the docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/cluster-singleton.html).

Comment: can you please tell which package contains Consumer.class  and also what is the type of queue? I don't have any queue in my code

Comment: Just copy pasting of code is not what I am expecting from a reputed so user.

Comment: You already know how to schedule messages, and with the extra detail of how to create and send messages to a cluster singleton it should be clear how to string it all together. You haven't specified in your question exactly how it isn't working. Maybe that would help bring you some better answers.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I am unable to understand the way further so kinda stuck.